# django built-in admin action delete - reason for bad performance?

Tags: python, django, database

I have been adding items from a txt to my database in a djago-view - with and without the `@transaction.atomic`-decorator, i.e. with a loop over db-writes or one db-write -- the performance difference is near infinite!^^

**Now my observation:** the default delete-action in the admin panel clearly does the (inferior) loop over db-wirtes. Which takes *really* long for deleting 1000 entries.

Why is this, is there a reason, am I missing something?!
Or should I fix this and open a pull request ;) (would be my first oss-contribution :))

As mentioned in the first answer, there is a confirmation step between chosing the action and the actual delete. But even after the confirmation it takes several minutes (for a few thousand entries) to delete the items, during which the database is locked, so there is no way back at that point...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When doing a bulk delete, neither the models `delete()` methods nor the eventual `pre_delete` and `post_delete` signals are invoked, so if your code relies on either of those you are in trouble. Hence the very sensible choice to loop over instances and call their `delete()` method individually. No need to report it as a bug (nor to submit a patch), it's actually a feature ;)

Comment: sounds sensible :)

Answer (score 1):

You could always add your own delete function using django's queryset.delete() function, as that does a bulk delete query.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/#delete

I think the reason the admin uses a loop for deletes, is that it asks you to confirm, and lists all the related objects that will be deleted. That will take some time if you have a large number of entries. (Though it is a lot safer than the bulk delete).

Create an action somewhere (I use a file actions.py).

```
def fast_delete(modeladmin, request, queryset):
    queryset.delete()
```

import that in your admin.py file, and add it to the actions of your ModelAdmin class.

```
from myapp.actions import fast_delete

MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAmdin):
    model = MyModel
    action = [fast_delete,]
```

Comment: Thank you for the comments on defining own admin actions. As to the built-in one: I see your point about the confirmation, but this is not the main delay. Even after the final confirmation (the queryset should be still accessible then?) it does the loop...

Comment: There's more to it than just asking for confirmation, cf my answer.